# AUTORECOVERY alternative for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to mimic Oracle `SET AUTORECOVERY ON` in SQL Server 2008 for applying transaction logs?

`RESTORE LOG [DB_NAME] FROM  DISK` requires backup name;  in case I have couple hundreds logs I must ensure logs are restored in proper order . Surely, I can sort files by name, but I wonder maybe there is out of the box solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You can reduce your dependency on a large number of log files by taking full backups more frequently or taking differential backups in between. The process is supposed to allow you to make restoring easier - it doesn't sound much easier if you have 200+ log files to restore.

Comment: If you are restoring back to the same server, and the backup history in MSDB is intact, the GUI tool makes these kind of restores a breeze!

Comment: Not the same server, logs go to standby db.  Restoring time is reasonable - 2 days logs can be applied within 10 minutes which is perfectly fine even in case of disaster (in my case).  My goal is to deliver logs to standby, but apply them once a day. This way I always have "safety" window in case I need to perform point-in-time recovery (which in practice happen way more often than need for failover).

Comment: You can still generate the scripts from MSDB on the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to mimic Oracle `SET AUTORECOVERY ON` in SQLServer 2008 for applying transaction logs?

No. SQL Server does not have this option.

What you can do ?

- Take often Full/differential backups (as suggested by @Aaron Bertrand). This highlights the importance of having a good backup (and restore) plan which is inturn dictated by your company's [RTO and RPO](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-accidental-dba-day-6-of-30-backups-understanding-rto-and-rpo/).
- Script out and often test your restores. A backup is ONLY good if you are able to restore it. You can use [sp_RestoreGene - T-sql version](https://paulbrewer.wordpress.com/sp_restoregene/) from Paul Brewer. It automates your restores.
- Implement **Logshipping** to a warm standby server. Logshipping is an automated process of backing up your primary database (Full backup followed by T-Logs set as per frequency (minimum is 1 mins)), copying the log files to a shared location on secondary and applying them on the secondary database. This will be a close option to `SET AUTORECOVERY ON` that you have in Oracle.

> My goal is to deliver logs to standby, but apply them once a day.

This is a perfect case of implementing [Logshipping](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2301/step-by-step-sql-server-log-shipping/). You can even delay applying transaction logs and have the secondary database in standby mode which can be used for reporting queries.

Alternatively, if you are on sql server 2012 Enterprise and up, then you can look into implementing [AlwaysON Availablity groups](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2013/08/19/step-by-step-creating-a-sql-server-2012-alwayson-availability-group/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with LogsShipping as it seems to fit my current needs.